# What is the generalization of Taylor's expansion with the fractional number as a power index?

Tags: taylor-expansion, fractional-calculus

Given a classical Taylor expansion as $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{d^{i}f(x_{0})}{dx^{i}}\frac{(x-x_{0})^{i}}{i!}$ where i is a nonnegative integer.

Can we generalize this expansion to fractional number $\alpha$ which satisfied $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{d^{(i\alpha)}f(x_{0})}{dx^{(i\alpha)}}\frac{(x-x_{0})^{i\alpha}}{\Gamma(i\alpha+1)}$ ? I am not sure this simple generalization is correct or not?

If it is not correct, what is the coefficient $b_{i}$ which satisfy $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} b_{i}(x-x_{0})^{i\alpha}$ ?

Comment: This is generally the idea behind any integral transform (Fourier, Laplace, etc are just "continuous" versions of Taylor series). If you specifically want fractional powers spaced at integral steps, then there is the [Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series)